# RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU if text too long?

Tags: android, text, sms

I use this code to send message programatically. I got "Null Pdu" if text too long.. if short, successfully send. Whats wrong? what is null pdu? can u fix guys? thanks 4 u help.. (sorry bad english)

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode())
    {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got some fix? I have the same problem :(

Comment: Yeah @Joubert Vasconcelos, solved if using sendMultipartTextMessage. Here sample code:  
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentPIList,deliveredPIList);

Answer (score 1):

You must divide all your text into parts so that they fit in a few sms. or send it as an MMS